# Disregard Discord messages that start with specific words (case insensitive)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Playing a game on Discord were I need to reply when a BOT (BOT1) pings me. BOT1 will just send a message at random times asking if I'm online. I can filter those messages with this line without issue.

`message.author.id == (int(bot1)) and f"<@{my_user_id}>" in message.content`

Issue:
Any user can ask bot1 if im online (by saying check or Check or CHEck, etc). Once they send that command, bot1 will send a regular check message to see if im on.
I need my bot (BOT2) to skip those on demand checks and only answer (...`send_delayed_msg(message.channel, f"<@{bot1}> im here", 1.91`) ) when bot1 sends the message `(...f"<@{my_user_id}>" in message.content)` on its own and not when another player makes it manually check.

The code below will respond 100% of the time bot1 pings me, even when a user invokes the "check" request.

```
    alt = os.environ['alt'] # this is to cover a few of the ways players can type cheCK



    @client.event  def on_message(message):
              if message.content.lower() == (alt):                 
                 os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)  # This restarts the app so it skips the elif 
              elif message.author.id == (int(bot1)) and f"<@{my_user_id}>" in message.content:
                 await send_delayed_msg(message.channel, f"<@{bot1}> c {catc}", 1.91)
```

Sorry, if I'm not expressing myself properly. This is my first python/coding project.

Thanks!